# Create empty block

Tags: forms, blocks

I want to create an empty block that could be edited by the administrator, but by default the block should contain a body.

The module block `block_custom_block_form()` contains the following code.

```
$form['body_field']['body'] = array(
'#type' => 'text_format',
'#title' => t('Block body'),
'#default_value' => $edit['body'],
'#format' => isset($edit['format']) ? $edit['format'] : NULL,
'#rows' => 15,
'#description' => t('The content of the block as shown to the user.'),
'#required' => TRUE,
'#weight' => -17,
```

);

How can I override this function to set #required to `FALSE`?

Answer (score 1):

[block_custom_block_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/block_custom_block_form/7) is called from [block_block_configure()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.module/function/block_block_configure/7), which an implementation of [hook_block_configure()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.api.php/function/hook_block_configure/7). Those hooks are called from [block_admin_configure()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.admin.inc/function/block_admin_configure/7), which is the form builder for admin/structure/block/manage/%/%.

The code used from the function to invoke the modules is the following one.

```
  $block = block_load($module, $delta);
  $form['module'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value', 
    '#value' => $block->module,
  );
  $form['delta'] = array(
    '#type' => 'value', 
    '#value' => $block->delta,
  );

  // Get the block subject for the page title.
  $info = module_invoke($block->module, 'block_info');
  if (isset($info[$block->delta])) {
    drupal_set_title(t("'%name' block", array('%name' => $info[$block->delta]['info'])), PASS_THROUGH);
  }

  $form['settings']['title'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield', 
    '#title' => t('Block title'), 
    '#maxlength' => 64, 
    '#description' => $block->module == 'block' ? t('The title of the block as shown to the user.') : t('Override the default title for the block. Use <em>!placeholder</em> to display no title, or leave blank to use the default block title.', array('!placeholder' => '&lt;none&gt;')), 
    '#default_value' => isset($block->title) ? $block->title : '', 
    '#weight' => -19,
  );

  // Module-specific block configuration.
  if ($settings = module_invoke($block->module, 'block_configure', $block->delta)) {
    foreach ($settings as $k => $v) {
      $form['settings'][$k] = $v;
    }
  }
```

Code similar to the following one should work.

```
function mymodule_form_block_admin_configure_form(&$form, &$form_state) {
    // Check the module implementing the block is the Block module, and not another one.
    if ($form['module']['#value'] == 'block' && isset($form['settings']['body_field']['body']))
    $form['settings']['body_field']['body']['#required'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

The function is an implementation of [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7), where FORM_ID is block_admin_configure, in your case.

If you are editing an enabled module, you need to first disable, and then re-enable it. Drupal saves in a cache the list of hooks implemented from modules; disabling, and re-enabling a module forces Drupal to clear that cache. Differently, Drupal will not notice you added a new hook to the already enabled module.

Comment: It doesn't work, this function is implemented on the block module not in the block custom module.

Answer (score 0):

For adding a block with an empty body, the hook should be "mymodule_form_block_add_block_form_alter". You can use the hook code from espero's answer, something like this:

```
function sf_random_form_block_add_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
    // Check the module implementing the block is the Block module, and not another one.
    if ($form['module']['#value'] == 'block' && isset($form['settings']['body_field']['body']))
    $form['settings']['body_field']['body']['#required'] = FALSE;
}
```